# Чем отличаются две функции c++

Tags: c++

Есть ли разница в приеме аргументов у этих функций

```
void func(Test const& t)
{
}
```

и

```
void func(const Test& t)
{
}
```

Comment: `void func(const &Test t)` — вы уверены? Именно так? Это не компилируемо... https://ideone.com/EL0M9J

Comment: @Harry извиняюсь, опечатался  void func(const Test& t)

Comment: `Test const& t` и `const Test& t` обозначают одно и то же - ссылку на неизменяемый объект типа `Test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет никакой разницы. И та, и та функция будет выполняться одинаково:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

size_t func(size_t const& t)
{
    return t;
}

size_t func2(const size_t& t)
{
    return t;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t num1 = 12345;
    const size_t num2 = 12345;
    cout << func(num1) << endl;
    cout << func(num2) << endl;
    cout << func2(num1) << endl;
    cout << func2(num2) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 1;
};
```

**Вывод в консоль:**

**12345**

**12345**

**12345**

**12345**

В принципе это логично. Вообще: компилятор и так понимает, что параметр не сможет измениться, но это не значит что `const` не нужно писать, ведь без него вы не сможете передать любые константные переменные/объекты:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

size_t func(size_t& t)
{
    return t;
}

size_t func2(size_t& t)
{
    return t;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t num1 = 12345;
    const size_t num2 = 12345;
    cout << func(num1) << endl;
    cout << func(num2) << endl;
    cout << func2(num1) << endl;
    cout << func2(num2) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 1;
};
```

**Не компилируется**

И ещё: для указателей важно расположение `const`.

**const size_t* ptrName** - Это указатель на константу, он не может менять значение переменной/объекта на который указывает, но может меняться сам.

**size_t* const ptrName**  - Это константный указатель. Он может менять переменную/объект на который указывает, но не может меняться сам.

**const size_t* const ptrName** - Это константный указатель на константу, несложно догадаться, что он не может менять и себя, и переменную/объект.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const size_t get_const_t_const(const size_t* const ptr)
{
    return *ptr;
}

size_t get_t_const(size_t* const ptr)
{
    return *ptr;
}

const size_t get_const_t(const size_t* ptr)
{
    return *ptr;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t var1 = 90;
    const size_t var2 = 100;
    size_t var3 = 110;

    const size_t* const const_t_const_ptr = &var1;
    const size_t* const_t_ptr = &var2;
    size_t* const t_const_ptr = &var3;

    cout << get_const_t_const(const_t_const_ptr) << endl;
    cout << get_t_const(t_const_ptr) << endl;
    cout << get_const_t(const_t_ptr) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 1;
};
```

**Вывод в консоль:**

**90**

**110**

**100**

Comment: `const T *x` равно `T const *x`, но не равно `T *const x`. Со ссылками первые два варианта равны, а третий не компилируется.

Comment: Но автор не просит решение задачи, он спрашивает результат и разницу (То есть код ему не нужен). Потому я и сделал скриншоты. @user207200

Comment: Я избавился от скриншотов. @user207200